# remote chunking: How to exchange data between master and slaves

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using spring batch remote chunking, and i have the folowing problem:
At the master side, i put some informations in the 'ExecutionContext/jobExecution' to get them back in the processor at the slave side, but slaves can not retreive this informations from 'ExecutionContext', because 'ExecutionContext' is null.

Is there a mecanism to exchange informations between master and slaves ?

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the items that are passed to be processed by the worker, there is no additional communication channel provided by Spring Batch between the master and workers.  I'd be interested in discussing thoughts and options if you wanted to open an issue up in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH).

Comment: Thank you for the replay @Michael. I have opened the requested issue on Jira.